# calculate the average value per minute in R

Tags: r, date, data.table, average

I have a `data.table` with two parameters(date and value), now I want to calculate the Average Value for each minute(or each 15 minutes).

- I thought at first I should seperate the date into hours and minutes
- then calculate the average value for the interval time

but I really have no idea how to do, maybe you would have an idea for it

For example, the simple data.

```
date                Value
2015-07-01 00:00:23 1.83
2015-07-01 00:00:24 1.68
2015-07-01 00:00:25 1.29
2015-07-01 00:00:40 14.23
2015-07-01 00:00:41 0.96
2015-07-01 00:00:46 4.93
2015-07-01 00:01:12 26.44
2015-07-01 00:02:02 49.66
2015-07-01 00:02:05 3.00
2015-07-01 00:02:08 3.19
2015-07-01 00:02:27 19.42
2015-07-01 00:02:32 4.44
2015-07-01 00:02:45 12.77
2015-07-01 00:02:49 4.44
2015-07-01 00:03:40 50.71
2015-07-01 00:03:50 10.64
2015-07-01 00:03:52 1.18
2015-07-01 00:03:52 0.99
2015-07-01 00:03:54 1.32
2015-07-01 00:03:56 2.20
```

Here is a code to generate test data:

```
dd <- data.table(date = c("2015-07-01 00:00:23", "2015-07-01 00:00:24", "2015-07-01 00:00:25","2015-07-01 00:00:40", "2015-07-01 00:00:46","2015-07-01 00:01:12","2015-07-01 00:02:02","2015-07-01 00:02:08","2015-07-01 00:02:27","2015-07-01 00:02:32","2015-07-01 00:02:45","2015-07-01 00:02:49","2015-07-01 00:03:40","2015-07-01 00:03:50","2015-07-01 00:03:52","2015-07-01 00:03:54","2015-07-01 00:03:56"),
             value = c(1.83,1.68,1.29,14.23,0.96,4.93,26.44,3.00,3.19,19.42,4.44,50.71,10.64,1.18,0.99,1.32,2.20))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `quarter`?

Comment: @RonakShah: Quarter of a year.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich How do you know it's not quarter of an hour or quarter of a minute?

Comment: If that is quarter of a year, then this data is not sufficient to represent the question. Also, it is not clear whether OP wants to add a new column or wants to aggregate for every quarter.

Comment: hi all, thanks for the attention, sorry for the unclear description, i just amended the text, hope it is now clear for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `minute` function from the `lubridate` package. Note that `data.table` has an `hour` function.

We can use the `cut` function to format the minutes into quarters of hours.

```
library(lubridate)
dd[, c('Hour', 'Minute') := .(data.table::hour(date), minute(date))
 ][, Minute_Cut := cut(Minute, breaks = c(0,15,30,45,60), include.lowest = T)
 ][, .(Avg = mean(value)), .(Hour, Minute_Cut)]

#    Hour Minute_Cut      Avg
# 1:    0     [0,15] 8.732353
```

If you just want to calculate by each minute, we can avoid the `cut` step:

```
dd[, c('Hour', 'Minute') := .(data.table::hour(date), minute(date))
 ][, .(Avg = mean(value)), .(Hour, Minute)]

#    Hour Minute      Avg
# 1:    0      0  3.99800
# 2:    0      1  4.93000
# 3:    0      2 17.86667
# 4:    0      3  3.26600
```

Comment: big thanks , it works with my dataset!!! still a lot of unknown packages for me !

Comment: @ZAWD Note that the latest development version of `data.table` has a `minute` function as well -- in fact, [I authored it](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/23dc0145d6b785300019aa5454295e78ee7459e1) ;-)

Comment: install via `install.packages("data.table", type = "source", repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")`

Answer (score 4):

Since you meant "quarter of an hour" when you said "by quarter", then I would convert your data.table to an xts object and use `xts::period.apply`.

```
library(xts)
x <- as.xts(dd[,date := as.POSIXct(date)])
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "minutes", 15), mean)
#                        value
# 2015-07-01 00:03:56 8.732353
```

---

If by "quarter" you mean "quarter of a year", then you can use my original answer:

You can use `zoo::yearqtr` to create a quarterly time value to aggregate by. Then use the normal data.table aggregation steps.

```
dd[, avg := mean(value), by = zoo::as.yearqtr(dd$date, "%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Comment: hi , @Joshua, thanks for the answer, how about if the interval time is 15 mins (quarter of an hour), so could i also use the funtion of zoo?